# rugarch: Understand forecasting

Tags: r, garch

I try to understand how to forecast with the rugarch package, especially the command [ugarchforecast][1].
I have problems with understanding the n.roll and the out.sample command. Can someone explain this exactly?

The n.ahead command is clear to me. It says how much steps I want to forecast ahead. If it is more than 1 period, then the previous data is not sufficient anymore and the method uses the forecast value of the one step ahead forecast, to calculate the two step ahead forecast. Ok I understand that.

> The ability to roll the forecast 1 step at a time is implemented with
> the n.roll
> argument which controls how many times to roll the n.ahead forecast. The default argument
> of n.roll = 0 denotes no rolling and returns the standard n.ahead forecast. Critically,
> since n.roll depends on data being available from which to base the rolling forecast, the
> ugarchfit function needs to be called with the argument out.sample being at least as
> large as the n.roll argument, or in the case of a specification being used instead of a
> fit object, the out.sample argument directly in the forecast function.

I do not want to use a rolling approach, so I do NOT want to reestimate the model every time step, so I do not understand what n.roll and out.sample gives me? What does it mean to "roll the forecast 1 step"? I mean, if I do n.ahead=1 forecasts, then I have constant parameters, since I do not reestimate the model every time step.. and then I do simple one step ahead forecasts. So I use one new observation to do the forecast.
[1]: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rugarch/docs/ugarchforecast

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found it out:

> I do not understand what n.roll and out.sample gives me?

n.roll gives you the number of the n-ahead forecasts. So you roll the window by one observation and you do the next n-ahead forecast. Out.sample is used to define the observations which should be excluded in the estimation procedure (if used in ugarchfit) to do out of sample forecasting afterwards.

> What does it mean to "roll the forecast 1 step"?

It means, you go to the next period and the the next n-ahead forecast, as I wrot above.

You may want to use fitted() and sigma(). These are the fitted values and due to the lagged character of GARCH this is already so to say a "forecast".